# continuous-time Markov chain

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Suppose a Markov chain has two states, and for any $t\geq 0$ we have $P(X_t=0)=P(X_t=1)=1/2$, then how to figure out the transition probability $\textbf{P}(t)$?

Comment: There will be symmetry but on that information you cannot really say any more

Comment: To demonstrate Henry's point, consider a MC which is fixed, either $0$ or $1$, each with probability $1/2$, on the other hand consider one where $X_{t+1}$ is independent of $X_t$. Both satisfy those conditions, but have different transition probabilities.